# Do I need a visa to go to New Zealand as a Filipino?

Tags: visas, new-zealand, filipino-citizens

I am a Filipino working in Japan (with Philippines Passport). I read somewhere that Japan is waived for NZ visa. I want to visit New Zealand but I do not have any idea whether I need a visa to do that.

Comment: Eligibility for visa free access to NZ depends only on your nationality, not on where you happen to reside at any given moment.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you will need a visa. Only Japanese passport holders (and holders of passports from [other visa-waiver countries](http://glossary.immigration.govt.nz/visafreecountries.htm)) can take advantage of a waived visa, not people who work in Japan under a foreign passport.

Answer (score 2):

The [IATA](http://www.iatatravelcentre.com/TR-Turkey-passport-visa-health-travel-document-requirements.htm) has an online resource to answer these type of questions. It seems (after entering some random data), that you need a visa.